# Need a way to shorten and make code more effective

Tags: r

I want to perform a bootstrap simulation 1000 times and compute percentile confidence intervals 1000 times for different samplesizes `n = 10,20,...,100`. I've solved this problem and I'm just asking, instead of doing this huge computations 10 times, covering 300 lines of code, is there a way to shorten this? Like, running this function over and over again 10 times? I tried a for-loop but it did not work. Here is the code that does work:

```
B                   = 1000              # number of replicates
kHat                = Parameters[1]     # approx = 2.06786
gammaHat            = Parameters[2]     # approx = 0.51144
TheoreticalMean     = kHat/gammaHat
TheoreticalVariance = kHat/gammaHat^2
PercCoverage        = vector("numeric", 10L)

n = 10    # sample size

getCI = function(B, k, gamma, n) {

  getM = function(orgData, idx) {
    bsM = mean(orgData[idx])                         
    bsS2M = (((n-1) / n) * var(orgData[idx])) / n    
    c(bsM, bsS2M)
  }

  F = rgamma(n, kHat, gammaHat)    # simulated data: original sample
  M   = mean(F)                    # M from original sample
  S2M = (((n-1)/n)*var(F))/n       # S^2(M) from original sample

  # bootstrap
  boots   = t(replicate(B, getM(F, sample(seq(along=F), replace=TRUE))))
  Mstar   = boots[,1]                 # M* for each replicate
  S2Mstar = boots[,2]                 # S^2*(M) for each replicate
  biasM   = mean(Mstar)-M             # bias of estimator M

  # indices for sorted vector of estimates

  idx   = trunc((B+1)*c(0.05/2,1-0.05/2))
  ciPerc  = sort(Mstar)[idx]              # percentile CI

  c(perc=ciPerc)
}

# 1000 bootstraps

Nrep <- 1000            # number of bootstraps
CIs  <- t(replicate(Nrep, getCI(B, kHat, gammaHat, n)))

# coverage probabilities

PercCoverage[1] = sum((CIs[,"perc1"]<TheoreticalMean) & (CIs[,"perc2"]>TheoreticalMean)) / Nrep
```

However, here I need to script this for `n=10`, `n=20` and so on to `n=100`, and each time I need to change `PercCoverage[1]` to P`ercCoverage[2]...PercCoverage[10]` in order to store these values in an array for later plotting.

I tried setting `n=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)` and then placing all of the above in a for loop but the function `getCI` needed numerical value.

EDIT: For loop attempt:

```
n = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
B                   = 1000              # number of replicates
kHat                = Parameters[1]     # approx = 2.06786
gammaHat            = Parameters[2]     # approx = 0.51144
TheoreticalMean     = kHat/gammaHat
TheoreticalVariance = kHat/gammaHat^2
PercCoverage        = vector("numeric", 10L)

for (i in length(n)){        

    getCI = function(B, k, gamma, n[i]) {

      getM = function(orgData, idx) {
        bsM = mean(orgData[idx])                         
        bsS2M = (((n[i]-1) / n[i]) * var(orgData[idx])) / n[i]    
        c(bsM, bsS2M)
      }

      F = rgamma(n[i], kHat, gammaHat)    # simulated data: original sample
      M   = mean(F)                    # M from original sample
      S2M = (((n[i]-1)/n[i])*var(F))/n[i]       # S^2(M) from original sample

      # bootstrap
      boots   = t(replicate(B, getM(F, sample(seq(along=F), replace=TRUE))))
      Mstar   = boots[,1]                 # M* for each replicate
      S2Mstar = boots[,2]                 # S^2*(M) for each replicate
      biasM   = mean(Mstar)-M             # bias of estimator M

      # indices for sorted vector of estimates

      idx   = trunc((B+1)*c(0.05/2,1-0.05/2))
      ciPerc  = sort(Mstar)[idx]              # percentile CI

      c(perc=ciPerc)
    }

    # 1000 bootstraps

    Nrep <- 1000            # number of bootstraps
    CIs  <- t(replicate(Nrep, getCI(B, kHat, gammaHat, n[i])))

    # coverage probabilities

    PercCoverage[i] = sum((CIs[,"perc1"]<TheoreticalMean) & (CIs[,"perc2"]>TheoreticalMean)) / Nrep
}
```

Comment: So why not just make this a function that takes `n` as a parameter? Have you just never written a function before? Is that the question? Or is there something else I'm missing here.

Comment: You mean just wrapping the entire code above in a function that only takes n?

Comment: Show us your `for` loop attempt.

Comment: @Parfait - Please see my edit.

Comment: @MrFlick - Thanks for taking time to answer this. I'm not sure what you intended here. I've written 2 functions in the script above, you want me to make a third?

Comment: You need to pass a sequence into `for`, specifically `1:length(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider defining multiple functions: a master one *boostrap_proc*, *gCI*, and *getM*. Then pass in your sequences of sample sizes in `lapply` for list return or `sapply` for numeric vector each calling the master function and returning a series of probabilities (last line of function). Be sure to remove the hard coded `n = 10`.

**Define** Functions

```
B                   = 1000              # number of replicates
kHat                = Parameters[1]     # approx = 2.06786
gammaHat            = Parameters[2]     # approx = 0.51144
TheoreticalMean     = kHat/gammaHat
TheoreticalVariance = kHat/gammaHat^2

bootstrap_proc <- function(n) {   
    Nrep <- 1000             # 1000 bootstraps
    CIs  <- t(replicate(Nrep, getCI(B, kHat, gammaHat, n)))

    # coverage probabilities
    sum((CIs[,"perc1"]<TheoreticalMean) & (CIs[,"perc2"]>TheoreticalMean)) / Nrep
}

getCI <- function(B, k, gamma, n) {     
    F <- rgamma(n, kHat, gammaHat)    # simulated data: original sample
    M   <- mean(F)                    # M from original sample
    S2M <- (((n-1)/n)*var(F))/n       # S^2(M) from original sample

    # bootstrap
    boots   <- t(replicate(B, getM(F, sample(seq(along=F), replace=TRUE),n)))
    Mstar   <- boots[,1]                 # M* for each replicate
    S2Mstar <- boots[,2]                 # S^2*(M) for each replicate
    biasM   <- mean(Mstar)-M             # bias of estimator M

    # indices for sorted vector of estimates
    idx   <- trunc((B+1)*c(0.05/2,1-0.05/2))
    ciPerc  <- sort(Mstar)[idx]              # percentile CI    
    c(perc=ciPerc)
}

getM <- function(orgData, idx, n) {
    bsM <- mean(orgData[idx])                         
    bsS2M <- (((n-1) / n) * var(orgData[idx])) / n    
    c(bsM, bsS2M)
}
```

**Call** Function

```
sample_sizes <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

# LIST
PercCoverage <- lapply(sample_sizes, bootstrap_proc)

# VECTOR
PercCoverage <- sapply(sample_sizes, bootstrap_proc)

# VECTOR
PercCoverage <- vapply(sample_sizes, bootstrap_proc, numeric(1))
```

Comment: Shame I did not figure this out myself. I understand exactly what you have done and it does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha...all part of the learning curve! Glad to help. Happy coding!